# Laravel massive assignment

Tags: php, laravel

Yii offers a convenient way to massive assignment to a model. I search on google and can't find any information about massive assignment with Laravel.
So, does Laravel offer the same functionality?

Comment: Massive assignment means?

Comment: in short you make all the variables contained in a post request to be persisted in the database without any efforts. So you dont have to map each request variable. in symfony , it is easy to do if you use Entities when you create an form in a controller action. The form will map the entity attributes when you bind it to the request ( $form->bind($request)) , that's mass assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

But make absolutely sure you white-list your attributes or you'll open yourself up to serious security issues.

Comment: Hi Bretty Johnson, I'm gonna mark your answer as accepted one. However, AFAK, Laravel also binds all values when doing mass-assigment, so it helps to prevent SQL injection automatically. So, I don't understand why you're saying: " you'll open yourself up to serious security issues. "

Comment: It's not to protect against SQL injection, it's to protect against a mass-assignment vulnerability. :)

Say you have a User model with a 'name' and 'isAdmin' property, and you have a form where the end user can update their info.  If you're using mass assignment in your form handler (e.g. $user = new User(Input::get());), and they modify the http post to include an input value named 'isAdmin' set to 'true', you've just allowed them to set themselves to be an admin.  Probably not a good thing. :)

Make sense?

Comment: Yep, and if the hacker changes a field to "id" I suspect the end result is wild west country, but could well involve taking over someones account.

Comment: In the docs you reference, it states, "All Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default." So I don't understand why whitelisting is needed. Could you explain?

Comment: I'm also curious why in the docs, they use "password" as a field that is guarded, since you would almost always want your users to be able to update that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried laravel yet, but a quick look on github tells me there's a function:

```
    /**
 * Hydrate the model with an array of attributes.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  bool   $raw
 * @return Model
 */
public function fill(array $attributes, $raw = false)
```

I guess you can do something like

`$product->fill($_POST['Product']);`

as you would do `$product->attributes = $_POST['Product']` in Yii